# Adding "Last updated on" in XeLaTex article

Tags: xetex, article

I am writing an article in `XeLaTeX` and I want to put a note on the bottom of the last page (may be in footer). This is what I have done-

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\updateinfo{\hfill\scriptsize\color{gray} Last updated on \today}

\begin{document}
The very long content goes here. The very long content goes here.
\updateinfo %Last updated on \today
\end{document}
```

However, this is not gonna work as I want, since it is not positioning the text on the bottom.
Please have a look.

Comment: Please supply only **working** examples. This one is missing a `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum: Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `\vfill` to push the text to the bottom. Like

```
\newcommand{\updateinfo}[1][\today]{\par\vfill\hfill{\script‌​size\color{gray}Last updated on #1}}
```

And note that the date given will be the date that you run LaTeX on it, which isn't necessarily the date of the last update. You can thus add an optional argument to specify another date:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \newcommand{\updateinfo}[1][\today]{\par\vfill\hfill{\scriptsize\color{gray}Last updated on #1}}

\begin{document}
    Without argument
    \updateinfo
\newpage
    With argument
    \updateinfo[November 24, 1991]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your concern. I am gonna make the date as an argument to this function, where the default is `\today`

Comment: `\newcommand{\updateinfo}[1][\today]{\par\vfill\hfill{\scriptsize\color{gray}Last updated on #1}}` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @piet I hope you don't mind I incremented on your answer...

Comment: @ebo Thanks for the addition. I will get the reputation anyway :)